# Access target branch name from GitHub Pull Requests in Cake

Tags: github, teamcity, pull-request, cakebuild

I'm working with Cake and Teamcity and I'm trying to access which branch a GitHub PR is targeting

Been trying to find a GitHub API wrapper for Cake do to the job, or a plugin/script to TeamCity to populate some parameter with the value, but no luck so far.

Is there any good wrapper for Github PR in Cake or TeamCity that i have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found and used the Octokit SDK for dotnet
https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net

As I for @Nils answer would also need the authorization for the repo to run the GIT commands, i went with a higher level solution more native to Cake

Answer (score 2):

I'm certain there is nothing that you have missed.

The question would be - before searching for how to do this in Cake - how to obtain the information in the first place.

If you were building on GitHub Actions, there is the `github.base_ref` which GitHub populates for PRs and which would contain exactly what you are looking for.

Now, I don't know how TeamCity does the checkout so I can probably not really help you. What I can do is give you a pointer:

What AppVeyor does when building a PR is this:

```
git clone -q <url of repo>
cd <name-of-repo>
git fetch -q origin +refs/pull/<gh-id-of-pr>/merge:
git checkout -qf FETCH_HEAD
```

If you - in that state - do

```
 git branch --contains HEAD^1
```

the output (at least in my tests) is:

```
* (HEAD detached at FETCH_HEAD)
  develop
```

As said above, I am not sure what TC does for a PR build but I guess you'd need something along the above lines.
I, personally, would try to get the required information using `git` commands before checking what the GitHub API can do.